# kendo ui grid is not receiving json data from servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, kendo-ui

[image: new html view]
i have a netbeans web application named javaservlet.this project package has one servlet databaseconnection.java.here i have retrieved 6 rows from a database table **employee** which has 3 columns **eid,ename,esalary** and show it as json value [image: jsondata]
 in "http://localhost:8084/javaservlet/databaseconnection" url.Now i want to show all 6 rows of data in kendo grid.In index.html page which is in WEB-INF folder i have tried to read json data from url.but it is not working.i have added three titles **EmployeeSalary,EmployeeName,EmployeeId** in kendo ui grid and three string fields.when i run the file only showing thevalue when database table has only one row but when table has more than one row kendo is not showing any data ..why is this happening.kindly help me to solve the problem.here is my code
databaseconnection.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.*;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/databaseconnection"})
public class databaseconnection extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test", "postgres", "root");
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
     //  String sql = "INSERT INTO employee (eid,ename,esalary) " + "VALUES (7, 'Nadia', 35000)";
        //  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("Select eid,ename,esalary from employee");
        while (result.next()) {
            String eid = result.getString("eid");
            String ename = result.getString("ename");
            String esalary = result.getString("esalary");
            jobj.put("eid", eid);
            jobj.put("ename", ename);
            jobj.put("esalary", esalary);
            out.print(jobj);
            out.flush();    

           // jArray.put(jobj);
            // System.out.print(jobj);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(databaseconnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

Comment: here is my index.html  of WEB-INF folder.through this page i want to show my json data in kendo grid http://pastebin.com/qSJx63qD

Comment: i am still trying with this problem.i have changed content-type as"application/json" both in servlet and jsp and got a little success now it is showing only one row in kendo..but not more than one row ..please help

Comment: when i run index.jsp file then it shows only first row of data of my database but json object is showing all 6 rows of data base.when the database table has only one row then kendo grid is working...

Answer (score 1):

Pls add the jsonobject into jsonarray inside the while loop.ex:

```
 while (result.next()) {
            String type_json = result.getString("eid");
            String name_json = result.getString("ename");
            String id_json = result.getString("esalary");
            jobj.put("eid", type_json);
            jobj.put("ename", name_json);
            jobj.put("esalary", id_json);
            **jArray.add(jobj);**

        }
```

Comment: when i add jArray.add(jobj); it was showing error then i changed it as jArray.put(jobj); but still kendo grid is not showing any data  i'm getting from servlet.now i have created new index.jsp page and set the content type as text/html and tried to show jsondata from servlet as i did in index.html.but still not showing data

Comment: i am still trying with this problem.i have changed content-type as"application/json" both in servlet and jsp and got a little success now it is showing only one row in kendo..but not more than one row ..please help

Comment: i have changed content-type as"application/json" both in servlet and jsp and got a little success now it is showing only one row in kendo..but not more than one row...kendo is working when database table has only one row..when table has more than one row then no data is visible

Answer (score 1):

Sara5, I think you should declare array object of Json class like below

```
JSONArray allArray = new JSONArray();
```

then

```
while (result.next()) {
        String type_json = result.getString("eid");
        String name_json = result.getString("ename");
        String id_json = result.getString("esalary");
        jobj.put("eid", type_json);
        jobj.put("ename", name_json);
        jobj.put("esalary", id_json);
        allArray.add(jobj);

    }
```

then after this , we create a default JSON object to contain all array and number of JSON objects as below

```
JSONObject myObj = new JSONObject();
myObj.put("success", true);
myObj.put("data", allArray); // all JSON objects
myObj.put("total", total);// total number of JSON objects

response.setContentType("application/json");// don't forget this
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println(myObj.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to use the below libs
json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15
commons-lang 2.5
commons-beanutils 1.8.0
commons-collections 3.2.1
commons-logging 1.1.1
ezmorph 1.0.6

change your code like this..
response.setContentType("application/json");

```
while (result.next()) {
            String type_json = result.getString("eid");
            String name_json = result.getString("ename");
            String id_json = result.getString("esalary");
            jobj.put("eid", type_json);
            jobj.put("ename", name_json);
            jobj.put("esalary", id_json);
            **jArray.add(jobj);**

        }
String output = jArray.toString();
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write(output);`enter code here`
    writer.close();
return "success";
```

The above code snippet will write the json output to the respective jsp whose forward is "success".

Comment: No it's not working :( but is it possible to capture the select query in a list and make the json object of that list to make this work? ..i havn't worked with json much before